# Why are there double brackets in character classes in POSIX?

Tags: regex

In POSIX, why does a character class such as `[[:digit:]]` have double brackets? Do the outer and inner brackets mean the same? Thanks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) defines a set of characters. Saying — "match **one** character specified by the class". `[:digit:]` is a POSIX character class and `[ ... ]` is a bracket expression here.

The POSIX class notation is only valid inside a bracketed expression. For example,
`[:digit:]`, when not inside a bracketed expression, will not be read as the POSIX named class. Rather, in most flavors it is the character class containing the characters (`:`, `d`, `i`, `g`, `t`) literally.

Comment: when is only one pair of brackets used?

Comment: For example when you want to match any character of letters or numbers, `[a-z0-9]`

Comment: Thanks. I meant when is `[:digit:]` used without another pair of brackets?

Comment: @Tim Never. Unless you want to match the equivalent of `[:digt]` (a plain regex character class matching any of the listed characters) in a confusing way.

Comment: A POSIX character class is a special metasequence of the form `[: ... :]` that can be used only inside a bracketed expression/regular expression character class.

Comment: For completeness, there are a few cases where character classes can be used outside of regular expressions, and in those cases, they aren't necessarily covered in `[`...`]`. A well-known example is the `tr` utility, where converting lowercase to uppercase looks like `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I know, that's why I wrote "outside of regular expressions" in my comment. :)

Answer (score 6):

The outer brackets indicate that any character enclosed with match.  The `[:digit:]` is the POSIX "any digit" character class.  For example `[[:digit:][:alpha:]]` says "any digit or any alphabetical character".  In ASCII, `[[:digit:][:alpha:]]` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Then when is only one pair of brackets used?

Comment: When you're not using POSIX character classes